# Replacing Numercal Months into Words in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this data inside my Array

```
var dateData = [2010-01-01 ,2010-02-20,2010-03-17,2010-04-11,2010-05-06,2010-05-31]
```

I will display this data under the X axis of my Chart using the below inbuilt function

```
xaxis: {noTicks:6,tickFormatter: function(n)
{
var k = Math.round(n);
return dateData[k]; 
}
```

My question is , can i replace the numeric months into Words while display ??

**For Example for 2010-01-01 i need 2010-JAN-01 , similarly for 2010-03-17 need 2010-MAR-17**

Comment: The way you mention it, dateData actually becomes `[2008, 1988, 1990, 1995, 1999, 1974]` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
var monthNames=['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY'],
    d='2010-01-23',
    a=d.split('-');
    a[1]=monthNames[a[1]-1];
    d=a.join('-');
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/herostwist/JWUqn/1/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have built-in date formatting functions. You could go with an external library (I recommend [this one](http://www.datejs.com/)) or simply create an object with names along the lines of

```
var month_names = {
    1: 'JAN', 2: 'FEB' // ..and so on..
}
```

And then use month numbers as keys into `month_names`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array (note empty 0th element):

```
var monthNames = ['','JAN','FEB','MAR',...];
```

Then you can simply write:

```
var monthNumber = 3;  // March
alert(monthNames[monthNumber]); // MAR
```

If using a javascript Date object, the months are indexed from zero so:

```
var monthNames = ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY',...];
var now = new Date();
alert(monthNames[now.getMonth()]); // APR
```

Comment: Thank you very much  , but in the middle 2010-03-17  that is 03 , how can i replace that ??

Comment: "2010-03-17".split('-'); //-> returns array ['2010', '03', '17']

Answer (score 0):

```
var monthNames=['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY'],
    date='2010-01-23',
    m=date.match(/-(\d\d)-/),
    newdate=date.replace(/-\d\d-/,'-'+monthNames[(RegExp.$1-1)]+'-');
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/herostwist/JWUqn/